# Getting error while using Observable.timeinterval() method

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am trying to use time interval in my observable code.

Following is my code

```
 Observable.just(listObj).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).
                flatMap(new Function<List<String>, Observable<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<String> apply(List<String> ints) {
                        return Observable.fromIterable(ints);
                    }
                }).toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.LATEST).subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {
                Log.d("Value kathe hai", s);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable t) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }
        });
    }
```

While trying to use

```
Observable.timeinterval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, scheduler)
```

I am getting different errors at different places depending upon the order in which I use it,in nutshell code is not allowing me to add this method after or before subscribe. How to use interval method in rxJava 2.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Periodic execution or measuring time between items?

Comment: @akarnokd It should emit those values with a certain time interval, till the list gets empty.

Comment: I can use a scheduler inside the observable method obviously, but why the defined method is not working ?

Comment: You should be using `subscribeWith(DisposableObserver`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zip it!

```java
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(
    Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
);


Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
   .zipWith(list, (time, item) -> item)
   .subscribe(System.out::println);
```